# .htaccess rewrite QUERY_STRING

Tags: .htaccess

one question please.

I have 2 files.

- index.php (my home)
- download.php (page download by "id")

---

## I need to replace (visualize) this:

> example.com/download.php?id=**95xdA93td**

## with this.

> example.com?**95xdA93td**

- I need to make this work. (Do not redirect)
- How can I have this result, without affecting my home (index.php)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /download.php?id=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^ download.php?id=%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: This rule affects the index. 
My **index.php** (home) now looks like the "download.php"
It does not work for me.